# Count rows from excel using python

Tags: python

I first read the table like this:

```
xls  = pd.ExcelFile("data.xlsx",header = None)
df = xls.parse('data', header=None)
```

Here is the result:

```
        0   1       2   3   4       5   6
0   291672  84885   1   1   0.03980 0   9
1   266227  77261   0   0   2.47720 1   0
2   264600  76722   1   1   1.79850 2   0
3   270364  78519   0   0   0.15620 0   5
```

My goal is to find for each combination of "5" and "6" column, count the number of each "2""3" combination, and get the average "4" of each type.

for example:

```
"5" "6" "2" "3" average"4" count()
 0   9   0   0    0.1222    23
 0   9   0   1    0.1222    45
 0   9   1   0    0.1222    24
 0   9   1   1    0.1222    12
         .....
```

I am quite new to Python. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, and might be improved if you provide us with a reproducible example that shows what you tried.  However, I think this might be what you want?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'foo':[5,2,2,4,4], 
        'bar':[5,2,1,1,1], 
        'baz':[.2,.3,.4,.5,.6], 
        'foo1':[2,2,2,1,1], 
        'foo2':[2,2,1,1,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
>
   bar  baz  foo  foo1  foo2
0    5  0.2    5     2     2
1    2  0.3    2     2     2
2    1  0.4    2     2     1
3    1  0.5    4     1     1
4    1  0.6    4     1     3

df.groupby(['foo','bar', 'foo1', 'foo2']).mean()

>
                   baz
foo bar foo1 foo2
2   1   2    1     0.4
    2   2    2     0.3
4   1   1    1     0.5
             3     0.6
5   5   2    2     0.2
```

Even if it's not quite what you wanted, you should still read up on `groupby` in Pandas, because that's definitely part of the solution.

Edit: Actually now that I read it again, this might be more accurate because of the count:

```
data = {'foo':[5,2,2,4,4], 
        'bar':[5,2,1,1,1], 
        'baz':[.2,.3,.4,.5,.6], 
        'foo1':[2,2,2,1,1], 
        'foo2':[2,2,1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.groupby(['foo','bar', 'foo1', 'foo2']).agg(['mean', 'count'])
>
                    baz
                   mean count
foo bar foo1 foo2
2   1   2    1     0.40     1
    2   2    2     0.30     1
4   1   1    1     0.55     2
5   5   2    2     0.20     1
```

Here I just used `agg` to pass two aggregation functions, which you can see collapsed the rows that were the same and raised the count to `2`.  Note that one of the values in `foo2` is changed from the first example to show this working.

Comment: Thanks! Let me check how to use groupby first!

Comment: The following code solved my problem! Thanks! `df.groupby(['5','6', '2', '3'])['4'].agg('mean,'count'])`